# Preciso inserir uma tag HTML com jQuery para encapsular o código abaixo?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Como inserir um elemento HTML depois da abertura e antes do fechamento da tag com jQuery?

Isso dentro de um `each`:

```
$("#main_div").append('<div class="Ftitulo">'+item.titulo+'</div>')
$("#main_div").append('<div class="Fdescricao">'+item.descricao+'</div>')
$("#main_div").append('<a href="' +item.arquivo+ '" class="Farquivo"></a>')
```

Faz isso:

```
<div class="Ftitulo">Cadastro de terreno na prefeitura para eventos</div>
<div class="Fdescricao">Cadastro de terreno na prefeitura para eventos</div>
<a href="9737f3bf65dfe7231002380876ecd1b0.jpg" class="Farquivo"></a>
```

Preciso disso:

```
<div id="pegatudo">
      <div class="Ftitulo">Cadastro de terreno na prefeitura para eventos</div>
      <div class="Fdescricao">Cadastro de terreno na prefeitura para eventos</div>
      <a href="9737f3bf65dfe7231002380876ecd1b0.jpg" class="Farquivo"></a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Acredito que isso possa resolver:

```
var pegatudo = $("<div/>",{id:"pegatudo"});

pegatudo.append('<div class="Ftitulo">'+item.titulo+'</div>');
pegatudo.append('<div class="Fdescricao">'+item.descricao+'</div>');
pegatudo.append('<a href="' +item.arquivo+ '" class="Farquivo"></a>');

$("#main_div").append(pegatudo);
```

Answer (score 3):

O jeito mais simples de se fazer, seria assim:

```
$("#main_div").append(
  '<div id="pegatudo">' +
    '<div class="Ftitulo">'+item.titulo+'</div>' + 
    '<div class="Fdescricao">'+item.descricao+'</div>' +
    '<a href="' +item.arquivo+ '" class="Farquivo"></a>' +
  '</div>'
);
```

Lembrando que ao usar o `.append`, ele vai adicionar o conteúdo (ao final) em um div com ID "main_div", já existente na pagina, mantendo todo o conteúdo atual dele.

Para substituir o conteúdo dele, pelo novo conteúdo use: `$("#main_div").html('conteudo');`

Answer (score 2):

Não sei se entendi sua pergunta certo, mas não seria isso?

```
var s;
$.each(...) {
     s = s + montarDiv();
});
$("#main_div").append('<div id="pegatudo">' + s + '</div>');


function montarDiv(){
    var texto;
    texto ='<div class="Ftitulo">'+item.titulo+'</div>';
    texto = texto + '<div class="Fdescricao">'+item.descricao+'</div>';
    texto = texto + '<a href="' +item.arquivo+ '" class="Farquivo"></a>';
    return texto;
}
```

Acredito que isso resolva.